# Mysterious grok filter syntax error

Tags: logstash-grok

So I have the following logstash filter config file.

```
filter {

  if [type] == "syslog" and [message] =~ "diskstation" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{INT:version} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program} - - (?:\[meta sequenceId="%{POSINT:message_id}"])? %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
    }
  } else if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) the filters work fine, but when starting logstash I get the following error:

```
Jun 03 11:49:38 nuc logstash[27352]: Error: Expected one of #, {, } at line 16, column 170 (byte 348) after filter {
Jun 03 11:49:38 nuc logstash[27352]: if [type] == "syslog" and [message] =~ "ds02" {
Jun 03 11:49:38 nuc logstash[27352]: grok {
Jun 03 11:49:38 nuc logstash[27352]: match => { "message" => "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{INT:version} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program} - - (?:\[meta sequenceId="
Jun 03 11:49:38 nuc logstash[27352]: You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
Jun 03 11:49:38 nuc logstash[27352]: use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
Jun 03 11:49:38 nuc logstash[27352]: to restart a running system.
```

I cant for the life of me figure out what the syntax error is. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was staring me in the face the entire time of course. The problem is the double quotes in the filter. Can be solved by using single quotes.

filter {

if [type] == "syslog" and [message] =~ "diskstation" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => '<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{INT:version} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program} - - (?:[meta sequenceId="%{POSINT:message_id}"])? %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}' }
    }
  } else if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
    }
  }
}